# Best approach to migrate huge amounts of data from Oracle 9i to Azure Hyperscale

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-migration, azure-data-factory, oracle9i

We have a requirement to transfer huge amounts of data from On-premise Oracle 9i to Hyperscale. I am trying to find the best possible approach to get this transfer happen. At the moment, I am using Azure Data Factory and it is taking more than 24 hours for the transfer and we don't have that much of a window while transferring data.

Also, my On-premise IR is on 16GB RAM with 4 Cores and the DTU's on Copy Activty on ADF is set to Auto.Can anyone suggest if this is the best approach that I am following or is there a better way ?

Note : I've checked that AzureDatabase Migration Service does not support Oracle 9i so I don't think that can be my approach.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @SDR, If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have any other concerns, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @SDR, did you get any progresses?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know how large data your Oracle database have, you can reference this Data Factory copy performance table:
[image]

To get the highly performant, we could follow the this document: [Copy activity performance and scalability guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#performance-tuning-steps):

You are copy data from On-premise Oracle to Hyperscale, we need the Self-host integration runtime. To achieve higher throughput, you can either scale up or scale out the Self-hosted IR. Ref: [Self-hosted integration runtime scalability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features#self-hosted-integration-runtime-scalability)

Or using more DIUs for the copy active:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. The data I am trying to copy in total is around 5 TB and I was testing a single table which is around 250 GB - This took me around 24+ hours on ADF using 256 DTU's and 100 parallel copies. My throughput is always around 3.5 - 4 MB/s. Not sure what exactly to do to improve the throughput. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @SDR usually, did you try using the more DIUs for the copy active? Please see the update.

Comment: Yes.. I meant I used 256 DIU's (maximum) and also set the Degree of Copy Parallelism to 100. I've also tried to enable staging but that did not help either - In fact that seemed to slow down the process altogether

Comment: Did you try to scale the Azure Hyperscale to a higher price tier?

Comment: My Hyperscale is set to Gen5 and 40vCores at the moment. This was previously set to 10 vCores and has been increased.